# Disable/Enable Grouping in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, grouping, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid whose first column is:

```
  columnDefs : [$scope.getGroupIdColumn(),
                $scope.getKlasCodeColumn(),
                $scope.getKlasNummerColumn(),
                $scope.getNaamColumn()
            ]
```

where `getGroupIdColumn` is:

```
    $scope.getGroupIdColumn = function () {
        var result = new Object();
        result["name"] = 'GroupID';
        result["visible"] = false;
        result["type"] = 'number';
        if ($scope.groupingEnabled) {
            console.log("komt toch: " + $scope.speedDial.grouping);
            var grObj = new Object();
            grObj["groupPriority"] = 0;
            result["grouping"] = grObj;
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Other column definitions are also like this.

If `groupingEnabled` is true, i have grouping. If false, without grouping. Until here, it works as excepted.

BUT

If i redefine that column, or even all the grid-options, it remains same as it is. Thus, if i have a grid with grouping and i redefine all grid options, i have still grid with grouping.

What should be done?

*PS: gridApi.core.refresh(), $evalAsync().. are tried and no any improvement.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just can't believe it was so easy! I'll write my functions which will be easier for people to get started: (also here is the [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.grouping.service:uiGridGroupingService))

1. Set gridApi in $scope:

   ```
   $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
       $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
   }
   ```
2. Save your grouping info:

   ```
   $scope.groupInfo = $scope.gridApi.grouping.getGrouping();
   ```
3. Just define these functions

   ```
   $scope.groupData = function () {
       if ($scope.groupInfo != undefined) {
           $scope.gridApi.grouping.setGrouping($scope.groupInfo);
       }
       setTimeout(function () {
           $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
       }, 400);
       $scope.$evalAsync();
   }

   $scope.ungroupData = function () {
       // if ($scope.groupInfo != undefined) {
           // $scope.groupInfo = $scope.gridApi.grouping.getGrouping();
       // }
       $scope.gridApi.grouping.clearGrouping();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For my case I needed to toggle grouping and I tried your answer but it do not work for me so I changed it a bit.

```
$scope.groupData = function () {
    $scope.gridApi.grouping.groupColumn('columnName');
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
    }, 300);
}
```

Working example http://plnkr.co/edit/AtcLSsqqnSaFeLfOEJhc?p=preview